# Monero 11.0 worked now I can't get 12.0 to load it crashes

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, user-guide

I'm a Windows 10 user. I had a working GUI in 11.0 (it took forever to get it working but yes it worked) and now I don't in 12.0. I've sent money after the fork using 11.0 (ignorant to the fork) and not only can I not get that back but I can't get the 12.0 GUI to load it at all. It works in the low-graphics mode but not the regular mode. How to resolve this?

Comment: Use that ^ guide to resolve your issue. Also, I am not entirely sure what the issue is with getting it to work if it starts with the `start-low-graphics-mode.bat`batch file. Note that the devs are aware that the graphics fallback is not working properly and this will be fixed in the upcoming point release.

Comment: Thanks I have another question why wouldnt the devs update themselves to prevent this type of annoyance? Wouldnt that make more sense for the software to update itself??

Comment: This was a bit of an oversight on our side. It should be a lot smoother the next fork, i.e., you, most likely, will not have to perform any manual steps to correct your blockchain. In sum, merely upgrading should be sufficient next time.

Answer (score 0):

Your funds are not gone as long as you kept your keys and know your passphrase. Have you tried running the GUI using a different computer?

Comment: With all respect and apologies this isn't going that well and I have a right to be frustrated and frankly that's what the large print is indicating

Answer (score 0):

Take a bit of time and learn Debian Linux.  It's simple and completely free.  Runs circles around Windows 10.   Crypto currencies work much better without Windows issues, including Monero.